# LINQ way to get items between two indexes in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have List of Employee objects. I need to select only two employee objects between two indexes (based on start and end variables). Following code works fine but it is not in LINQ. What is the best `LINQ` code for this purpose?

Note: I am looking for `Method Chain` approach

**CODE**

```
public static class DatabaseSimulator
{

    public static List<Employee> GetData(string name, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        List<Employee> searchResult = new List<Employee>();
        List<Employee> employeesSource = SearchEmployees(name);

        int start = ((index - 1) * pageSize)  + 1;
        int end = (index * pageSize);
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if (searchResult != null)
            {
                int listCount = employeesSource.Count;
                for (int x = 0; x < listCount; x++)
                {
                    if (x == i)
                    {
                        searchResult.Add(employeesSource[x]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return searchResult;

    }


    private static List<Employee> SearchEmployees(string name)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
        return employees.Where(r => r.Name == name).ToList();
    }

    private static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.EmpID = i;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 2";
            }
            else if  (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 3";
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 5";
            }
            else if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 7";
            }
            else 
            {
                emp.Name = "Other -- "+ i.ToString();
            }

            employees.Add(emp);
        }

        return employees;
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
List<Employee> searchResult = DatabaseSimulator.GetData("Divisible by 2", 2, 2);
```

Comment: Note that you should not always create new lists with `ToList`(f.e. in `SearchEmployees`) when you chain these methods. That is very inefficient. Instead just return the query and call `ToList` at the end.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Do you mean I need to return `IEnumerable` rather than `List` ?

Comment: Yes. In this case it would be better to provide overloads of `SearchEmployees` with/without the start- and end-index).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `list.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex)` construct.

Where

`startIndex` : is an index of the *first* item to select

`endIndex` : is and index of the *last* item to select

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Take(endIndex - startIndex + 1)` ?

Comment: @Lijo: it depends on if you want to include edge elements too. The legitimate question also could be: *shouldn't be it (startIndex + 1)?*.

Comment: Following the string.substring way it should be as lijo says. In any case this is awesome. Thanks